# how to implement curve animation in cocos2d ios

Tags: android, ios, android-emulator

In my application, I'm using COCOS-2D here I need to move one dot based on path, if click button that time that dot position needs to increment 10(like Progress Bar), I tried using Bezier Curve animation but it's not fit for my application,

Can anyone suggest me how to do this ?

Please see below image and suggest me when I click button that dot needs trace the curve a bit position: 
[image]

```
  CCBezierConfig bezier = CCBezierConfig.config();
        bezier.startPosition = CCPoint.ccp(0, 0);
        bezier.controlPoint_1 = CCPoint.ccp(0, s.height / 2);
        bezier.controlPoint_2 = CCPoint.ccp(300, -s.height / 2);
        bezier.endPosition = CCPoint.ccp(300, 100);

        CCIntervalAction bezierForward = CCBezierBy.action(3, bezier);
        CCIntervalAction bezierBack = bezierForward.reverse();
        CCIntervalAction seq = (CCIntervalAction) CCSequence.actions(bezierForward,  bezierBack);
        CCAction rep = CCRepeatForever.action(seq);
     grossini.runAction(rep);
```